# How do I compare a specific cell with a column range and return a string associated with the column range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

Thanks for reading my first question. I'm just starting out with google sheets to please bear with me.
[Here is the sheet I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPw4Q.png)

So,this sheet if for a game I play and we assign guild attacks based on power levels. I'm looking to create a function or script and put it in Column O. I'd like this function to compare Column F to a specific cell in Column M and then return the user associated with Column F that is >= than the specific cell in Column M. Like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUHCg.png)
I highlighted the first three as an example.

I can obviously do this manually but I takes time, and was looking to automate this process so it becomes more efficient. I've tried Vlookups, MATCH, IF and I've been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Again, I'm just a beginner with google sheets so please go easy on me.  :)

Comment: To clarify: are there other factors you look at when manually determining which ```ATTACKER``` gets sorted at the top? I can't easily see why ```treadinglight``` doesn't have the top spot in ```Column O``` unless that user chose to attack a different ```Place``` because they have the highest ```Heroes power```? If possible, can you also share the doc (or at least a copy of it)?

Comment: Of course. Here is the document (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D3To8rCiiVPJuNctfWPZuzNJycVaeqKpDzl8MwfZkgU/edit#gid=1763178775).  To answer your question, the only factors we look for is if titan power is higher than the opponents titan power by 2000 points. The users are sorted by Hero Power.
I don't necessarily want to match our top player with the top opponent. Say if we have 3 possible players that have a higher titan power than one of the opponents. I want a formula or script to randomly assign one of those three players to that opponent.
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

As you metioned that you would also be happy with an scripted solution I have created this script that I believe solves your issue. It has comments explaining step by step how it works:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get our sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Automate Test');
  
  // Get the values of the ranges of F and M. Flat will convert the 2D array we get from getValues() into a 1D one which is easier to work with
  var valuesF = ss.getRange('F2:F16').getValues().flat();
  var valuesD = ss.getRange('D2:D16').getValues().flat();
  var valuesM = ss.getRange('M2:M16').getValues().flat();
  var valuesN = ss.getRange('N17:N31').getValues().flat();
  
  
  // We will iterate through all the players in column M to find their opponents
  for(i=0;i<valuesM.length;i++){
    // We create an empty array to be filled with the list of possible opponents to then choose a random one of the list
    var playersHigherEqual = [];
    
    // Iterate through the opponent list
    for(j=0;j<valuesF.length;j++){
      // If the opponent meets the condition
      if(valuesF[j]>= valuesM[i]){
        // Add it to the array of possible opponents
        playersHigherEqual.push(ss.getRange(j+2, 2).getValue());
      }
    }
    
    //Finally we will set the opponent by choosing a random one out of the list. Note that i+2 is because the arrays start from 0
    ss.getRange(i+2, 15).setValue(playersHigherEqual[Math.floor(Math.random()*playersHigherEqual.length)]);
  }
  
  
  // We will iterate through all the players in column M to find their opponents
  for(i=0;i<valuesN.length;i++){
    // We create an empty array to be filled with the list of possible opponents to then choose a random one of the list
    var playersHigherEqual = [];
    
    // Iterate through the opponent list
    for(j=0;j<valuesD.length;j++){
      // If the opponent meets the condition
      if(valuesD[j]>= valuesN[i]){
        // Add it to the array of possible opponents
        playersHigherEqual.push(ss.getRange(j+2, 2).getValue());
      }
    }
    
    //Finally we will set the opponent by choosing a random one out of the list. Note that i+2 is because the arrays start from 0
    ss.getRange(i+17, 15).setValue(playersHigherEqual[Math.floor(Math.random()*playersHigherEqual.length)]);
  }  
  
}
```

**Please let me know if you also need a sheet formula solution for this question**. For more information about Apps Script check out [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to do. If I wanted to include the Hero Columns I was just add those to the **get range** section correct? For some reason I can't post code in this comment. Also, is there a way to optimize this to where it makes an "optimal" battle plan? I'm curious to know what a sheet formula would look like for learning purposes. Only when you get a chance. You've been such a big help!  :)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you saw my previous comment

Comment: Hi ! For adding code to a comment just put three ``` ``` ``` around your code like ``this`` (but 3 instead). What do you mean by adding the **Hero Coumns**, do you mean the hero power? Also, what do you exactly mean with **optimal battle plan** ? How do you calculate or get that? Also, please consider accepting my answer if it worked for you so that other users with similar questions can easily see a solution :D

Comment: That's strange. I accepted it a couple of days ago. Just accepted again, sorry about that. Yes, I mean Hero Power. The above script populates a random opponents for Titans, but I also want to do the same for Hero Power as well. I felt like I should add this to the script somewhere.
```var valuesF = ss.getRange('D2:D16').getValues().flat();
  var valuesM = ss.getRange('N2:N16').getValues().flat();```

Here is my document to take a look at [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D3To8rCiiVPJuNctfWPZuzNJycVaeqKpDzl8MwfZkgU/edit#gid=1763178775)

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to have the users populate based on hero powers just like we did with the titan powers.  What I mean by "optimal" is if you look at the user that was populated for titans you see tha it populated treadinglight 3 times. We only have two attacks. Also, treadinglight or erock should be paired with the 158000 opponent. So, in this game we all have only 2 attacks. We can attack two titan teams, two hero teams, or a titan and a hero team. Does that make sense? Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  :)

Comment: Hi ! I have updated my answer to cover also the heroes case. What do you mean exactly with the part of ```treadinglight or erock should be paired with the 158000 opponent``` ?  Do you want to only pair strong teams with strong teams and weak teams with weak teams ? If so, following the Stack Overflow guidelines that should be asked as a new question as it is on top of this first question :D